# Equivalent of R packages automation tools in Python

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, python-packaging

I'm an R user. I'm used to, when creating a project in R, developing an R package. Simply because R packages have a standard structure of file organization, naming, conventions, etc... So that makes life way easier. Whenever I need a new R package, I simply go on RStudio and "Create New Package". If I need to use tests or add dependencies, I'll use `usethis` package and that pretty much does it for me.

Now I'm doing a bit of a switch to Python and... How would I do the same? I can create some python scripts, define some dependencies. But what is the "convention" for doing python projects? I know there's a pattern defined by https://pypi.org/.

Is there a way to automate such pattern creation, just like RStudio automates R packages developing?

Comment: I'd suggest starting with https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html. And yes, there are several frameworks that will spit out templated projects for you, but requests for software recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: Didn't you just recommend setuptools? Which one of these frameworks, in your opinion, would be a good start?

Comment: I did place a recommendation, but in a comment, not an answer; _answers_ are more strictly required to comply with topicality rules, as are questions.

Comment: ...as for templating tools, dunno -- I don't use them. Back when I was building webapps, pretty much every webapp framework (Django and its contemporaries) provides its own quick template engine, but if you aren't using anything that fancy there's hardly a point; create a minimal `setup.py` listing your dependencies, run `mkdir src test`, put your files under that `src` directory, your tests in the `test` directory and there you are (and even that much is a matter of opinion and taste; setuptools doesn't _require_ a `src` directory at all).

Comment: https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Comment: Would any of you care to answer the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually, I found an online book that was exactly what I was looking for. https://py-pkgs.org/ is pretty much a complete guide (from design practices to unit tests, documentation and whatnot) for making python packages using automation tools such as `cookiecutter` and `poetry`. The key point is that the whole book is inspired by the process of making R packages, which is what I was looking for.